# localizing attributes is not working

Tags: laravel, localization

I am trying to localize filed name in validation error message using `attributes` array in `resources/lang/{my_language}/validation.php`:

```
return [
'accepted' => 'يجب قبول :attribute',
'active_url' => ':attribute لا يُمثّل رابطًا صحيحًا',
'after' => 'يجب على :attribute أن يكون تاريخًا لاحقًا للتاريخ :date.',
'after_or_equal' => ':attribute يجب أن يكون تاريخاً لاحقاً أو مطابقاً للتاريخ :date.',
'alpha' => 'يجب أن لا يحتوي :attribute سوى على حروف',
'alpha_dash' => 'يجب أن لا يحتوي :attribute على حروف، أرقام ومطّات.',
'alpha_num' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute على حروفٍ وأرقامٍ فقط',
'array' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute ًمصفوفة',
'before' => 'يجب على :attribute أن يكون تاريخًا سابقًا للتاريخ :date.',
'before_or_equal' => ':attribute يجب أن يكون تاريخا سابقا أو مطابقا للتاريخ :date',
'between' => [
    'numeric' => 'يجب أن تكون قيمة :attribute بين :min و :max.',
    'file' => 'يجب أن يكون حجم الملف :attribute بين :min و :max كيلوبايت.',
    'string' => 'يجب أن يكون عدد حروف النّص :attribute بين :min و :max',
    'array' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute على عدد من العناصر بين :min و :max',
],
'boolean' => 'يجب أن تكون قيمة :attribute إما true أو false ',
'confirmed' => 'حقل التأكيد غير مُطابق للحقل :attribute',
'date' => ':attribute ليس تاريخًا صحيحًا',
'date_format' => 'لا يتوافق :attribute مع الشكل :format.',
'different' => 'يجب أن يكون الحقلان :attribute و :other مُختلفان',
'digits' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute على :digits رقمًا/أرقام',
'digits_between' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute بين :min و :max رقمًا/أرقام ',
'dimensions' => 'الـ :attribute يحتوي على أبعاد صورة غير صالحة.',
'distinct' => 'للحقل :attribute قيمة مُكرّرة.',
'email' => 'عنوان البريد الإلكتروني غير صالح',
'exists' => 'القيمة المحددة :attribute غير موجودة',
'file' => 'الـ :attribute يجب أن يكون ملفا.',
'filled' => ':attribute إجباري',
'image' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute صورةً',
'in' => ':attribute لاغٍ',
'in_array' => ':attribute غير موجود في :other.',
'integer' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute عددًا صحيحًا',
'ip' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute عنوان IP صحيحًا',
'ipv4' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute عنوان IPv4 صحيحًا.',
'ipv6' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute عنوان IPv6 صحيحًا.',
'json' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute نصآ من نوع JSON.',
'max' => [
    'numeric' => 'يجب أن تكون قيمة :attribute مساوية أو أصغر لـ :max.',
    'file' => 'يجب أن لا يتجاوز حجم الملف :attribute :max كيلوبايت',
    'string' => 'يجب أن لا يتجاوز طول النّص :attribute :max حروفٍ/حرفًا',
    'array' => 'يجب أن لا يحتوي :attribute على أكثر من :max عناصر/عنصر.',
],
'mimes' => 'يجب أن يكون ملفًا من نوع : :values.',
'mimetypes' => 'يجب أن يكون ملفًا من نوع : :values.',
'min' => [
    'numeric' => 'يجب أن تكون قيمة :attribute مساوية أو أكبر لـ :min.',
    'file' => 'يجب أن يكون حجم الملف :attribute على الأقل :min كيلوبايت',
    'string' => 'يجب أن يكون طول النص :attribute على الأقل :min حروفٍ/حرفًا',
    'array' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute على الأقل على :min عُنصرًا/عناصر',
],
'not_in' => ':attribute لاغٍ',
'not_regex' => 'صيغة :attribute غير صحيحة.',
'numeric' => 'يجب على :attribute أن يكون رقمًا',
'present' => 'يجب تقديم :attribute',
'regex' => 'صيغة :attribute .غير صحيحة',
'required' => ':attribute مطلوب.',
'required_if' => ':attribute مطلوب في حال ما إذا كان :other يساوي :value.',
'required_unless' => ':attribute مطلوب في حال ما لم يكن :other يساوي :values.',
'required_with' => ':attribute مطلوب إذا توفّر :values.',
'required_with_all' => ':attribute مطلوب إذا توفّر :values.',
'required_without' => ':attribute مطلوب إذا لم يتوفّر :values.',
'required_without_all' => ':attribute مطلوب إذا لم يتوفّر :values.',
'same' => 'يجب أن يتطابق :attribute مع :other',
'size' => [
    'numeric' => 'يجب أن تكون قيمة :attribute مساوية لـ :size',
    'file' => 'يجب أن يكون حجم الملف :attribute :size كيلوبايت',
    'string' => 'يجب أن يحتوي النص :attribute على :size حروفٍ/حرفًا بالظبط',
    'array' => 'يجب أن يحتوي :attribute على :size عنصرٍ/عناصر بالظبط',
],
'string' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute نصآ.',
'timezone' => 'يجب أن يكون :attribute نطاقًا زمنيًا صحيحًا',
'unique' => 'قيمة :attribute مُستخدمة من قبل',
'uploaded' => 'فشل في تحميل الـ :attribute',
'url' => 'صيغة الرابط :attribute غير صحيحة',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
| with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
|
*/

'attributes' => [
    'name' => 'الاسم',
    'username' => 'اسم المُستخدم',
    'email' => 'البريد الالكتروني',
    'first_name' => 'الاسم الأول',
    'last_name' => 'اسم العائلة',
    'password' => 'كلمة السر',
    'password_confirmation' => 'تأكيد كلمة السر',
    'city' => 'المدينة',
    'country' => 'الدولة',
    'address' => 'عنوان السكن',
    'phone' => 'الهاتف',
    'mobile' => 'الجوال',
    'age' => 'العمر',
    'sex' => 'الجنس',
    'gender' => 'النوع',
    'day' => 'اليوم',
    'month' => 'الشهر',
    'year' => 'السنة',
    'hour' => 'ساعة',
    'minute' => 'دقيقة',
    'second' => 'ثانية',
    'title' => 'العنوان',
    'content' => 'المُحتوى',
    'description' => 'الوصف',
    'excerpt' => 'المُلخص',
    'date' => 'التاريخ',
    'time' => 'الوقت',
    'available' => 'مُتاح',
    'size' => 'الحجم',
    'nickname' => 'اسم العنوان'
],
```

but it's not working even-though I am clearing cache:

> php artisan config:cache

Still having the field name in the message:

> nickname مطلوب.

any idea?

Comment: Can you show the entire contents of the validation.php ?

Comment: @Tuim I updated the question

Comment: Hmm, it should work. You aren't giving any translations to the validator?